# Opening a client-side Excel file using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am the middle of writing a program which has to create an excel file on a client machine and then, after they have saved and updated it then I need to import it again and apply the changes to my database.  The export bit of it works fine, however when I import from the web application I get zero worksheets in my workbook.  If I run it on my development machine, i.e. the website is running on the same machine as the file is located then it works fine.

My code is as follows:

```
try
    {
        Productsfile = new FileInfo(PathandFileName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblStatus.Text = string.Format("Error getting file info {0}", ex.Message);
        return;
    }

    lblStatus.Text += "File Opened succesfully " + Productsfile.FullName + Environment.NewLine;

    //Open and read file
    try
    {
        using (ExcelPackage datafile = new ExcelPackage(Productsfile))
        {

            ExcelWorkbook wkb = datafile.Workbook;


            if (wkb != null)
            {

                lblStatus.Text += string.Format("The workbook is not null and there are {0} worksheets", wkb.Worksheets.Count) + Environment.NewLine;
```

I have confirmed that the code gets to the last label update, which tells me there are zero worksheets in the workbook, but importantly that the workbook itself is not null.

When we created the export the following code was used, which transfers the data stream from server to client - I am wondering if something to reverse it is needed:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Products.xlsx");
        Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
        Response.End();
```

Comment: A few questions: Is the file that's uploaded in the 2nd step the same file? Because in the 1st step, the user can use a different file name to save to the local client machine. Then upload a different file... Is the file exported in the 1st step generated correctly? Maybe that file had empty worksheets in the first place. That would explain the non-null workbook but empty worksheets situation.

Comment: Hi, the file is created server side and then streamed to the users machine using the Response code above.  They then select the file to upload and this is where it fails.  It would appear from the research I've done that the file is assumed to be on the server and opened from there, which doesn't exist.  The default for ExcelPackage when a filename doesn't exist is to create a new, blank workbook which I think explains the zero worksheets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, I believe I've found the answer:

1) Get the file details from a fileupload control
2) Convert this to a memory stream
3) Create the package using the memory stream

And the code is as follows:

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {

            HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[0];
            myLabel.Text = file.FileName;
            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
            mem.SetLength((int)file.ContentLength);

            file.InputStream.Read(mem.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)file.ContentLength);

            ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(mem);


            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
            myLabel.Text += " " + worksheet.Name;

        }
```

Comment: Hello Guys. Any idea if its possible to read a client side excel file without using an upload control? The file will be in the same location all the time.

Comment: It's possible using modern browsers, and IE10 or later. The browser must support the [FileReader https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader] web API. Check out [SheetJS http://sheetjs.com/] to read an Excel file from Javascript, with some examples.